# Deepin Game Center on Saucy?

Tags: 13.10, games

Is there a way to install Game Center from latest Deepin release onto Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 1):

To install Linux Deepin Software Center 3.0, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/deepin-sc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install deepin-software-center
```

<sup>Source:[NoobsLab](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/07/deepin-software-center-version-30-and.html)</sup>

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I was looking for the Game Center (Deepin Games or Deepin Games Center), do you know any PPA for that?

Comment: Take a look at http://mirror.bjtu.edu.cn/deepin/pool/main/d/deepin-game-center/